# dateFromString returns nil every time format possibly wrong?

Tags: swift, date

I am trying to use date from string method like below:

```
var dateNow = self.tags![indexPath.row].date!
let timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
df.timeZone = timeZone
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm"
let date: NSDate = df.dateFromString(dateNow)! //this is nil and throws an unwrapping error
```

The date is formatted like this

```
dateNow String  "2015-04-19T17:00:42.205Z"
```

Im guessing maybe that is formatted wrong but I have no idea how to write the df.dateFormat

Comment: yea those formats don't match!

Comment: You could modify the date string and remove the parts that are not necessary, then parse it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just have to format it as follow:

```
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Comment: Replace `hh` by `HH` in Leonardo's answer and it works (24 hour format).

Comment: awesome this works thank you! I get so confused with this formatting language thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Yet another way to get nil is if you use hh and your hours are on the 24 hr clock and > 12, in that case, you need HH (or H, for zero-padded).

**That is:**

Format: **yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss**, string: "2016-03-01 13:42:17" will return nil .

Format: **yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss**, string: "2016-03-01 13:42:17" will return the date you expect.

Comment: How does this answer the users original question?